# Pandas- Selecting the columns with specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge csv file and i want to filter out the dataframes with a specific value.

```
dataf = pd.read_csv('table.txt', sep=',')
dataf[(dataf.Subject_code == '100')]
#print (dataf[(dataf.Subject_code =='100')])
```

It returns an empty data frame. I get only the headers of the file. I need all the dataframes whose subject code is equal to 100.

Student   Subject_code   Score
1           100         A
10          500         B
12          100         A
15          100         C

Comment: This question seems malformed.

Comment: Is there some sample data we can look at? Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: are you sure it's a string column ? try `dataf[(dataf.Subject_code == 100)]`

Comment: Sorry, Im having a hard time posting the entire question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas most likely converts strings representing numbers to numbers (you can find out by doing `dataf.info()` and see if the column is numeric or `Object`. If it does, you should do equality check against `100` not `"100"`.

Comment: oh. okay. makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
print(dataf[dataf.Subject_code == 100])
```